# New field in ELK stack - logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am creating new field and copy data from existing one with:

```
mutate {
  add_field => { "NewField" => "%{[Old][Field]}" }
}
```

The problem that I am having is, prior this copy operation the OldField looks well presented in kibana in this way:

```
{
  "message": "1"
}
{
  "message": "2"
}
{
  "message": "3"
}
{
  "message": "4"
}
```

After copying the NewField represents the data in one line:

```
{message=1},{message=2},{message=3},{message=4}
```

Is there a way to keep the original formatting? The old field is a JSON array, the new field is text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [`copy`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-copy) instead of `add_field`?

```
mutate {
  copy => { "[Old][Field]" => "[NewField]" }
}
```

Comment: Blimey that actually worked, I wonder what the difference is, I was reading `add_field` as - "create new field and copy the data from existing one". I guess the logic behind copy and new_field is slightly different, although they seem to be doing the same thing - creating a new field and populating it with data from existing one. @julien-poulin any ideas why those two behave differently? Thank you!

Comment: I think the secret might be lying in the "%" symbol?

Comment: `add_field` allows you to concatenate/format fields (e.g. `"%{[field1]} - %{[field2]}"`), so it probably does some kind of "`toString()`" on them